# "Classify $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_8 / \langle(1,1,1)\rangle$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I have a question that says this:

> Classify $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_8 / \langle(1,1,1)\rangle$ according to the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.

I would like to see how it is correctly answered. This is not homework; I'd just like to see a proof.

Comment: What does that notation even mean? It would make a bit more sense if the thing inside the angle brackets were a _triple_, which could be understood as an element of $\mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_8$, but having a _pair_ there looks rather strange. And are you sure you mean "$\setminus$" (set difference) rather than "$/$" (qoutient)?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Corrected! I did mean the quotient.

Comment: How about the pair?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm sorry. It looks like I can't read this morning. I've corrected the pair as well; it should have been a triple.

Answer (score 5):

To make this a more or less computational manner, consider
$$
\mathbb Z_5\times\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_8\big/\left\langle(1,1,1)\right\rangle
\cong
\mathbb Z^3\big/U,
$$
where
$$ U=
\left\langle
\pmatrix{5\\0\\0}, \pmatrix{0\\4\\0}, \pmatrix{0\\0\\8}, \pmatrix{1\\1\\1}
\right\rangle.
$$
Now our goal is to find bases of $U$ and $\mathbb Z^3$ (both as $\mathbb Z$-modules) that reveal the structure of the quotient. Use the fact that $\gcd(5,8)=1$ and $8=2\cdot 4$ to obtain
$$ U=
\left\langle
\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}, \pmatrix{0\\4\\0}, \pmatrix{0\\1\\1}
\right\rangle.
$$
Where those $3$ elements of $\mathbb Z^3$ are now $\mathbb Z$-linearly independent. Now we pick a similar basis of $\mathbb Z^3$, namely
$$
\mathbb Z^3 = 
\left\langle
\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}, \pmatrix{0\\1\\0}, \pmatrix{0\\1\\1}
\right\rangle.
$$
Thus, the quotient kills two of the basis elements and leaves us with
$$
\mathbb Z^3\big/U \cong \langle(0,1,0)\rangle\big/\langle(0,4,0)\rangle \cong \mathbb Z_4.
$$

In the end, this is just linear algebra over $\mathbb Z$, which is a little bit more tricky since we can't divide, but you get the gist of it. You might be interested in [Smith normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), which basically tells you how to choose bases for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $\langle(1,1,1)\rangle$ means the subgroup generated by $(1,1,1)$, or in other words $\{(k\bmod 5,k\bmod 4,k\bmod 8)\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$.

In that case we can see that each of the cosets that make up the quotient must contain an element of the form $(0,x,0)$. Namely, assume that $(a,b,c)$ is *some* element of the cosets; then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem we can find $k$ such that $a\equiv k\bmod 5$ and $c\equiv k\bmod 8$. Subtracting $(a,b,c)-(k,k,k)$ gives us an alement o the form $(0,x,0)$.

On the other hand, $(0,x,0)$ is can only be zero in the quotient when $x\equiv 0\bmod 4$ (because if $(0,x,0)\equiv(k,k,k)$ then $k\equiv 0\bmod 8$ and therefore $k\equiv 0\bmod 4$.

So the quotient group is $\mathbb Z_4$.

What this has to do with the structure theorem I don't know, though. Perhaps you're supposed to start by rewriting it to $\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_{40}/\langle(1,1)\rangle$?

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, let $\mathcal G = \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_8 / \langle(1,1,1)\rangle$

Since $\text{ord}\langle(1,1,1)\rangle = 40$, then $\text{ord} 
(\mathcal G) = \dfrac{5 \times 4 \times 8}{40} = 4$

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320861/characterizing-the-cosets-of-a-cycle-of-a-finite-abelian-group-with-a-linear-com) we compute

```
 a:  5  4  8
 s:  1  1  1
 g:  1  1  1
 m:  5  4  8
 p:  5  1  8
 t:  1  4  1
 r:  1  4  1
 α:  1  0  0
 ω:  1  1  1
 β:  1  0  0
```

And conclude that every $(x,y,z) \in \mathcal G$ can be expressed uniquely as

$$(x,y,z) = \kappa(1,1,1) + \lambda(0, 1, 0)$$

where $0 \le \kappa \lt 40$ and $0 \le \lambda \lt 4$

Consequently, $\mathcal G \cong \mathbb Z_4$

Answer (score 0):

The Smith Normal Form of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 5&0&0\\ 0&4&0\\0&0&8\\1&1&1\\\end{pmatrix}$ (which gives a presentation for the group) has diagonal entries 1, 1, 4;
thus the group is isomorphic to $Z_4$.